# Joomla create html page with no menu

Tags: static, joomla

I have a normal article page with a huge image shown as a small one. What i want to do is, when the user click on the image, a new page is rendered and the image is shown at full size of the page (no menus, header, footer, etc.. just page). If the user click again, he will be redirected to the previous page.

How can i do this with joomla? I mean, i could create an html page, but i don't know how can i access it.

Any help would be appreciated,

RR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add this to any link you want to display without all of the module positions -

```
?tmpl=component
```

This tells Joomla to load just the component part of the page without anything else around it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that anything specifically in Joomla is going to allow you to do that. The only way you can achieve that directly in Joomla would be using a light box type of plugin. When the user clicks the image, it will open up a full size window of the image. When the user click on the image again, it will exit the light box.

Otherwise, you can just edit the source code of the page, and change it to `<a href="http://www.pathtoyourimage.com/image.png"><img src="http://www.pathroyourimage.com/image.png"></a>` . That way when a user clicks the image, they go directly to the picture.